# Doxygen Alias randomly printing paragraph html tag

Tags: html, markdown, documentation, alias, doxygen

new to doxygen and its config!

I have created a new alias within my external.cfg config file.

```
ALIASES                += frmnam{1}="\@frmnam=\1"
```

within the header of all our markdown pages we have a copyright notice, as you can see I have added the alias tag to the top of the paragraph.

**Markdown**

```
# Client Details
<p style="display:none">
@frmnam{clientAttributes}
@version 1
@copyright The company.com
@date 1996-2022
@brief Client Attributes
</p>
```

as you can see below the generated output we get additional `</p>` at the end of line 1 and `<p >` at the start of line two.

**HTML Output**

```
<p  style="display:none"></p>
<p >@frmnam=clientAttributes  
@version 1
@copyright The company.com
@date 1996-2022
</p>
```

[image: screen shot]

**Required Output**

```
<p style="display:none">
@frmnam=clientAttributes  
@version 1
@copyright The company.com
@date 1996-2022
</p>
```

Does anyone know how to stop this from being generated.
I have tried multiple variations, putting the HTML in the alias itself but no joy.
Any help would be gratefully received

thanks

Edited, doxy -x output (had to remove some path names)

```
C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin>doxygen -x "C:\Dev\########\########\WMS\########\WMSDev\Core\Product\doxyman.man.external.eng.cfg"
warning: Tag 'CLASS_DIAGRAMS' at line 2238 of file 'C:\Dev\########\########\WMS\########\WMSDev\Core\Product\doxyman.man.external.eng.cfg' has become obsolete.
         To avoid this warning please remove this line from your configuration file or upgrade it using "doxygen -u"
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.9.3 (c0b9eafbfb53286ce31e75e2b6c976ee4d345473)
PROJECT_NAME           = "######## External Guide"
PROJECT_BRIEF          = "######## External Guide"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = C:\Dev\########\V60\########\doc\eng\external
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = C:\Dev\########\########\WMS\########\WMSDev \
                         C:\Dev\########\V60\########\doc\src \
                         C:\Dev\########
ALIASES                = "intransaction=\n<b>Transaction control is managed by calling function.</b>" \
                         "outtransaction=\n<b>Transaction control is managed within function. Commit and Rollback internally.</b>" \
                         frmnam{1}=\@frmnam=\1
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = pc=C \
                         s=C \
                         msg=md \
                         txt=md
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
SHOW_FILES             = NO
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = NO
WARN_LOGFILE           = C:\Dev\########\V60\########\build\doxygen.external.eng..txt
INPUT                  = C:\Dev\########\########\WMS\########\WMSDev\Core\Product \
                         C:\Dev\########\########\WMS\########\WMSDev\WMSRep\Database\01_Tables
FILE_PATTERNS          = *ClientAttributes*.md
RECURSIVE              = YES
IMAGE_PATH             = C:\Dev\########\########\WMS\########\WMSDev\Core\Product
FILTER_PATTERNS        = *.md=C:\Dev\########\########\WMS\########\WMSDev\WMS\Utilities\python\doxy.md.imagemanual.py
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = Config.Main.md
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = C:\Dev\########\V60\########\include
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you usung? Please specify the differences between your used doxygen settings file and the default settings (i.e. the result of `doxygen -x`). Please provide a, small, real input example so we can try to reproduce the problem you face.

Comment: Hello, yes that would be helpful, here you go 
C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin>doxygen --version
1.9.3

when Im calling doxygen all it has is the path to the .cfg file, this has many config option as im sure you know

Comment: So what is specific in your config file (i.e. the output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`)  and how does the example look like?

Comment: Update in my question, thanks

Comment: Doxyfile looks OK, though would like to see a code example and also the results of the example (when it is an `md` file) after applying the filter, as specified with `FILTER_PATTERNS        `, on it .

Comment: The header from the md file is in the main question, then the actual html output is there as well as the required output. I dont know where the extra parameter tags are coming from

Comment: There is alot more text and images in the markdown file but this is just a snippet, thanks

Comment: OK getting  somewhere. You gave a textual representation of the HTML output could you place a screenshot in it? You need just a md file (e.g. aa.md) with the contents of the markdown snippet and a `Doxyfile` with just that one `ALIASES` in it. Poblem I also have is what is the intention of the `@frmnam=clientAttributes` in the HTML output?

Comment: Screenie added .......... So I need to add tag (@frmnam=clientAttributes) to the markdown file so what when doxygen runs we can have some html hidden text in the html outputfile.
The "clientAttributes" is actually a screen name in the application so its a link from the application screen to the screens documentation.
finally when we have the HTML output I run a python script to find the tag and html file and insert into the DB so then the user click help on a screen we can link them directly to the correct html page

Comment: if you take the <p></p> away from line 1 and 2 the block is hidden and I can then go to the next step of running the python script, I just cant get tag to write correctly :-(

Comment: Strange that the `@version` etc are still literal in your code, probably you manipulated in the filter script some things. I think that you are after `\htmlonly[block]` ... `endhtmlonly` and place the mentioned reference here (you don't need the `ALIASES` for this). Probably there are some other possibilities  as well that don't require all the workarounds, but can be directly used in doxygen. Will be hard to guess as I think you are working on propriety code and it will not be possible to get all the relevant information.